# nginx + php can't mkdir despite correct permissions

Tags: php, linux, permissions, nginx, mkdir

```
www@srv:/$ ls -lAh /data/
drwxrwxr-x 654 www www  20K Aug 21 00:01 history

ls -lAh /data/history/
drwxrwxrwx    19 www www 4.0K Aug 21 10:58 2012-08-21
```

So I have a directory 2012-08-21 and permissions seem to be OK...

PHP and Nginx both run as www:www for sure...

However...

```
Warning: mkdir(): Permission denied in /www/sites/mine/shop.php on line 366
string(57) "dir: /data/history/2012-08-21/1104-DAD2974M/"
```

Comment: What about the permissions on `/data/history/2012-08-21/`?

Comment: That's what I showed you in:

ls -lAh /data/history/
drwxrwxrwx    19 www www 4.0K Aug 21 10:58 2012-08-21

Comment: Ahh, so you did.  If those are your permissions, and you're still getting a permission issue, then your PHP process isn't running as www:www - meaning you need to triple-check your FCGI or FPM setup to determine exactly which user is running the script (or add an ``echo `whoami`;`` to your script)

Answer (score 1):

If you are certain that your servers are running as `www`, then you need to check the permissions on `/data/history/2012-08-21/`. It may not permissions to allow creating a directory within it.

The permissions on the `history` directory are not enough to review, you have to look at the next level as well.